# undefined local variable or method `autocomplete_skill_name' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Bellow is my code and files:
Rails 4 with gem 'rails4-autocomplete'

file: users_controller.rb

class UsersController < ApplicationController

before_action :confirm_logged_in, :except => [:create, :login, :attempt_login, :logout]

autocomplete :skill, :category_name

..
.

file: user.rb
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base

```
has_secure_password
has_many :skills
```

..
.

file: _form.html.erb

.
..

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :skills, autocomplete_skill_name, 'data-delimiter' => ',', :multiple => true %>
```

..
.

file: routes.rb

```
resources :skills do

  get :autocomplete_skill_name, :on => :collection
end
```

I have some skills ( :category_name ) - 3 records
and I can't seem to enable autocomplete on the field

Getting:

NameError in Users#edit

Showing [my local path]/users/_form.html.erb where line #42 raised:

```
*
```

> undefined local variable or method `autocomplete_skill_name' for

*

Would be happy for any assistance.

Thanks

Comment: Great, but now the field contains this value:

---- net- PHP- HTML- CSS- JQuery- Javascript

instead of the list of values.
basically :skills contains an array of values, and the field should contain multi multi values saved inside "skills" field on the user model.

Answer (score 1):

on your form use :autocomplete_skill_name rather then autocomplete_skill_name

Comment: it's a shame the original documentation provides misleading information